# How to detach and reattach elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to adjust a page to be more responsive. I have created 2 divs - one for mobile resolution  and one for screens resolution.

I have a form in each of them which should get data from db using ajax. Each div contains the same elements :form, inputs and submit button.

I need to detach one of the divs in each resolution for the ajax request to work because otherwise - the request could not handle 2 elements with the same name and classes....

I've tried to work it out in css using `display:none` - but still - the element appears.

What I wish to achieve is detaching the ( mobile ) and attaching another instead.

I need something like this :

```
var screen = $('#screen');
var mobile = $('#mobile');

    if ($(window).width() > 916) {

        $('#screen').detach();
        $('#mobile').append('.container');//this won't work

    }
    else {
        $('#mobile').detach();
        $('#screen').append('.container');//this won't work

    }
```

Here is my base layout. [Fidddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/roybarak/v05okx2q/1/)

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container col-md-12">

  <div id="mobile" class="col-md-12">

    <form class="form_filter" action="" method="post">
      <div data-provide="datepicker" class="input-group date has-feedback">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </div>
        <input id="date_customFrom" type="text" placeholder="From date" name="date_customFrom" class="form-control filter_dates" /><span class="form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div data-provide="datepicker" class="input-group date has-feedback">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </div>
        <input id="date_customTo" type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" placeholder="To date" name="date_customTo" class="form-control filter_dates" /><span class="form-control-feedback">        </span>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="submit btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
    </form>

  </div>

  <div id="screen" class="col-md-12">

    <form class="form_filter" action="" method="post">
      <div data-provide="datepicker" class="input-group date has-feedback">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </div>
        <input id="date_customFrom" type="text" placeholder="From date" name="date_customFrom" class="form-control filter_dates" /><span class="form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div data-provide="datepicker" class="input-group date has-feedback">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </div>
        <input id="date_customTo" type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" placeholder="To date" name="date_customTo" class="form-control filter_dates" /><span class="form-control-feedback">        </span>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="submit btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would seem more applicable to use a responsive stylesheet than it would be to hack the DOM around on resizing the window. Also, the two versions of your form seem identical? If you do want to follow on with the pattern you have, I'd suggest just using `show()` and `hide()` instead of adding or removing entire elements.

Comment: I'm assuming this code is inside a `resize` event handler?

Comment: if both contain the same data and elements why you need two ?? why not just change the styles with CSS mediaqueries?

Comment: Carl Edwards - I did tried it for start but it's not working - the problem is with attaching the elements....

Comment: To make this work you need to use `appendTo('.container')`, not `append()` and also run the code within a `$(window).resize()` event handler: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/v05okx2q/4/. I'm not going to add this as an answer though, because frankly it's an atrocious solution to the problem. You should really use CSS as @CarlEdwards answer shows you

Comment: DaniP  - I did used media queries for some of the changes but only when i detaching using jquery it works fine. can't reattach though.

Comment: But the real question is why you need two elements if are just the same ....

Comment: Rory McCrossan  - Thanks - i will consider doing it the right way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by your attempted code, you need to use the cached versions you store to the variables

```
var screen = $('#screen');
var mobile = $('#mobile');

if ($(window).width() > 916) {

    $('#screen').detach();
    mobile.appendTo('.container'); //this should now work
}
else {
    $('#mobile').detach();
    screen.appendTo('.container'); //this should now work
}
```

---

But you should really approach this through CSS and media queries.
(*Your code as it currently stands has issues in that it contains duplicate IDs in the HTML, and is pointless since both forms are identical*)

Comment: Ok - i surrender - i will use css :)

Comment: `$(window).width()` is not enougth . You need to add a [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) and use `.observe` on the `.container` itself , for example if the user opens devtools the window size doesnt change but the container did change size ... you can at least use `$(document).width()` instead .

Answer (score 3):

You could go pure CSS via media queries:

```
#mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 916px) {
  #screen {
    display: none;
  }

  #mobile {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It's a much, much better idea than what the OP was attempting. Even better still would be to use the same elements, but change their display properties between media settings.

Comment: *I've tried to work it out in css using display:none - but still - the element appears.* ..... the element still appears on the DOM so the ajax request don't work ... dup ID's and more

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be, being the `<form>` elements identical, to keep only one of them and change the css for the mobile version with

```
@media (max-width: 916) {
   form input {
      /* your input css for mobile version */
   }
}
```

so that you can manage all the dimensions of devices you want.

But, if you must use 2 different `<form>` elements, as pointed out by @Carl Edwards, you shoul be able to hide one of them with no problem in submission of data.

If you are having trouble getting the data because you get all data contained in the page you can try with something like

```
$('form').submit(function(){ var data = $(this).serialize(); }
```

or, if you have a function in which you get the `$('form')` directly, use `$('form:visible')`

If you absolutely need to detach your elements, go with

```
var screen = $('#screen').detach();
var mobile = $('#mobile').detach();

if ($(window).width() > 916) {

    $('#screen').detach();
    $('.container').append(mobile);

}
else {
    $('#mobile').detach();
    $('.container').append(screen);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ocr0y6g4/)**

```
var screen = $('#screen');
var mobile = $('#mobile');

if ($(window).width() > 916) {

  $('#screen').detach(); //only remove #screen element from the html
  //$('#mobile').append('.container'); //this won't work

} else {
  $('#mobile').detach(); //only remove #mobile element from the html
  //$('#screen').append('.container'); //this won't work

}
```

I have commented the view with the relevant display here. You do not need to call `.append()` as the html is initially loaded with both the sections (screen as well as the mobile section). Only after the javascript has calculated the screen width will the relevant section be detached. So out of the 2 sections in the html which come from the server, you only need to `.detach()` the relevant section. Hope it helps

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks. Updated. @RoryMcCrossan